# unable to install php5-mcrypt

Tags: 14.04, php

I want to install php5-mcrypt, I used this command to install mcrypt on my ubuntu 14.04 server:
`sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt`
and I'm getting the error like this,
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-mcrypt : Depends: phpapi-20100525
               Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.35-1~dotdeb.1) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
please help me.

Comment: Try `apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -f`

Comment: thanks aroll605. i tried that method it didn't work.so i removed phpand installed again on my system.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer to my question.
I removed php completely in my system using `sudo apt-get -y purge php.*`
and install php again on my system.
reference to remove php:
[How to completely remove PHP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59886/how-to-compelety-remove-php)

Comment: You can mark this question as answered if you solved it.