# localhost phpmyadmin displaying only codes

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed apache2 , php7.2.5 and mysql-server and also install phpmyadmin. Apache2 , php and mysql are running well. But when i try to run phpmyadmin , it displays a bunch of code in the browser. 
Looks like this:

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Main loader script
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/**
 * Gets some core libraries and displays a top message if required
 */
require_once 'libraries/common.inc.php';

/**
 * display Git revision if requested
 */
require_once 'libraries/display_git_revision.lib.php';
require_once 'libraries/Template.class.php';

/**
 * pass variables to child pages
 */
$drops = array(
    'lang',
    'server',
    'collation_connection',
    'db',
    'table'
);
foreach ($drops as $each_drop) {
    if (array_key_exists($each_drop, $_GET)) {
        unset($_GET[$each_drop]);
    }
}
unset($drops, $each_drop);
```

Help me to fix this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I used the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

If it doesn't resolve your problem, uninstall `php` and everything associated with it as described in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59886/how-to-completely-remove-php), using the command:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'php*'
```

after that reinstall `php` with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install php
```